# NLTK tokenizes exclamation and question marks inside quotes

Tags: python, string, nltk, quotes

For the input:

```
"Hello! What is your name?"My name is ABC.
```

Output which I'm getting is:

```
"Hello!

What is your name?"

My name is ABC.
```

I want to get the output as an entire sentence like:

```
"Hello! What is your name?" My name is ABC.
```

Please suggest some changes which I must make in the code.

This code is to extract sentences from a paragraph. Sentences are ones ending with full stop, exclamation mark and question mark. But if these are present inside quotes, it should then not divide the paragraph.

For example if it's `'"Hello! What is your name?"My name is ABC.'` then it should return the entire thing as a whole sentence and not divide when it encounters the exclamation mark and the question mark.

```
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktSentenceTokenizer, PunktParameters
punkt_param = PunktParameters()
punkt_param.abbrev_types = set(['dr', 'vs', 'mr', 'mrs', 'prof', 'inc'])
sentence_splitter = PunktSentenceTokenizer(punkt_param)
text =str(input())
text = text.replace('!"','!" ').replace('?"','?" ').replace('."','." ').replace('.','.').replace('?','? ').replace('!','! ')
sentences = sentence_splitter.tokenize(text)
for j in sentences:
    print(j)
```

Comment: If you want the output on one line, why are you `print`ing each sentence separately (and why is each one referred to as `j`?!)?

Comment: Trying to extract sentences from paragraph. Each sentence is to be displayed in new line.

Comment: That is the exact opposite of what your question says, which is that they are currently on new lines but you want them on one line.

Comment: Sentence will be ending with a full stop. The above code return right answer if the paragraph is like- "Hello! What is your name" My name is ABC. It return the entire thing as one line. But when there's a question mark added it returns the statement, after the question mark, on a new line.

Comment: controversial point on how a sent_tokenizer should act but i understand why the OP would need a tokenizer for such an input and the desired output.